# SQL query to INSERT a set of values, multiple times WHERE the number of times and one of the values is determined by the result of the WHERE cause

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to make a query to insert same set of values into a table, multiple times, with on of the values being an ID number from another table, and the results of another where clause determining the list of ID's

I was using something similar to the query below to pull up a list of company names from the database that have a particular type of product type installed (custom pricing etc)
Currently the list would be used to manually add a new product to the database for each of the companies in that list (front end only has interface to add from the company record)

I want to add identical products to all of that list of companies, so my plan was to adjust the query below to list the CompanyID numbers and use that list:

```
Use DBNAME
SELECT DISTINCT CompanyName
FROM CompanyList JOIN ProductList
ON CompanyList.CompanyID = ProductList.CompanyID
WHERE ProductList.ProductTypeID IN (71,72,73)
ORDER BY CompanyName
```

---

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [ProductList] ON
    
INSERT [dbo].[ProductList]
([ProductID][Name],[ProductTypeID],[Cost],[WholesaleRate],[UndeID],[Limit],[Days],[SortOrder],[Expired],[CompanyID])
VALUES
(-1,'ProductF',77,3.9,5.75,7,0,0,1,No,???)
    
SET  IDENTITY_INSERT [ProductList] OFF
```

I expect I need to replace CompanyName with CompanyID in the where, and combine the two in a way that wraps them in a transaction and allows the insert to step through the results of the where, maybe passing each result to the insert as a variable?

But I am not sure where to begin.

Thank you for your help, if anyone else has this issue please see below the final working result derived from the Marked best answer:

```
Use CVR_Sandbox
begin transaction
   
INSERT INTO [dbo].[ProductList] ([Name], [ProductTypeID], [Cost], [WholesaleRate], [UndeID], [Limit], [Days], [SortOrder], [Expired], [CompanyID])
    SELECT DISTINCT         'TESTPRODUCTname', 79, 3.9, 5.75, 7, 0, 0, 1, 0, cl.CompanyID
    FROM         CompanyList cl
    JOIN         ProductList pl ON cl.CompanyID = pl.CompanyID
    WHERE         pl.ProductTypeID = 71
    ORDER BY         cl.CompanyID

rollback transaction
--commit transaction
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write something like this - an `INSERT INTO` based on a `SELECT`, where most of the values are constants (as defined in your second query in your question).

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [ProductList] ON
    
INSERT INTO [dbo].[ProductList] ([ProductID], [Name], [ProductTypeID], [Cost], [WholesaleRate], [UndeID], [Limit], [Days], [SortOrder], [Expired], [CompanyID])
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        -1, 'ProductF', 77, 3.9, 5.75, 7, 0, 0, 1, No, pl.CompanyID
    FROM 
        CompanyList cl
    JOIN 
        ProductList pl ON cl.CompanyID = pl.CompanyID
    WHERE 
        pl.ProductTypeID IN (71, 72, 73)
    ORDER BY 
        cl.CompanyName
    
SET  IDENTITY_INSERT [ProductList] OFF
```

Not sure why you're doing an `IDENTITY_INSERT ON` and then inserting the same value -1 for each row...... since identity columns typically are primary keys - this might be a recipe for disaster (and errors) ...... do you **REALLY** need this?? Why not just let the database hand out the identity values?? That's what you've defined them for, after all .....

Comment: Thank you
I'll toss this solution at the test db and see what comes out the other side!  
I mashed together the data (-1) from a file based import routine that can go through the front end, with a previously used sql query (using IDENTITY_INSERT) i'd saved for inserting something based on a recommendation i had received at that time.   
It was likely relevant then, but not for this case, and I sadly didn't know any better.

I assume based on your statement that i should simple remove the -1 value and [ProductID] field name from the insert, and the DB should add the new IDs right?

Comment: @Wayne: exactly - just let the database dish out the new ID  values for the rows being inserted - that's what it's designed to do

Comment: I've removed the [ProductList], from the list of fields, and its data from the following line.    I've removed the INDENTIFY_INSERT on and off.   I also am getting an error with the pl.CompanyID)  at the end of line 4.   I thought it was because it was used before it was declared lower down, but  just realised the bracket after has no counterpart before.  I've removed that bracket and try in a sandbox now.